# Different action-angle variables for a 2D harmonic oscillator

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism, integrable-systems, integrals-of-motion

Consider a bidimensional harmonic oscillator.

Ref. 1 says that, when the frequencies are commensurable,

> separating the variables in cartesian or polar coordinates leads to
>   different action-angle variables

(and ultimately to different invariant tori)...but I can not figure how. Could someone offer an example?

References:

1. V.I. Arnold, *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics,* 1989; $\S51$ p. 291 Example 1. Read it [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=Pd8-s6rOt_cC&pg=PA291&lpg=PA291&dq=%22different%20action-angle%20variables%22%20arnol%27d&source=bl&ots=uMnjwHKCKC&sig=5IXhIkBQJqMnotvkzmIadCRSj5M&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjdi9jt9_HfAhXkz4UKHcrMDnYQ6AEwCHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22different%20action-angle%20variables%22%20arnol'd&f=false) or [here](https://loshijosdelagrange.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/v-arnold-mathematical-methods-of-classical-mechanics-1989.pdf).

Comment: Where does Arnold talk about commensurable frequencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ and in rectangular coordinates $$(x,y)~=~r(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$$ the 2D harmonic oscillator has Lagrangian
   $$L ~=~\frac{1}{2}(\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\theta}^2-r^2)~=~L_x+L_y, $$ $$L_x~=~\frac{1}{2}(\dot{x}^2-x^2), \qquad L_y~=~\frac{1}{2}(\dot{y}^2-y^2), $$ 
   and Hamiltonian
   $$H ~=~\frac{1}{2}(p_r^2+\frac{p_{\theta}^2}{r^2}+r^2)~=~H_x+H_y,$$
   $$ H_x~=~\frac{1}{2}(p_x^2+x^2), \qquad H_y~=~\frac{1}{2}(p_y^2+y^2), $$
   where
   $$r^2~=~x^2+y^2, \qquad p_r^2~=~p_x^2+p_y^2, \qquad p_{\theta}~=~xp_y-yp_x. $$
2. The [angle-action variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action-angle_coordinates) are 
   $$ (\varphi_r,\theta, H, p_{\theta})\qquad\text{and}\qquad(\varphi_x,\varphi_y, H_x, H_y),$$
   respectively, where
   $$ p_r+ir~=~\sqrt{2H}e^{i\varphi_r}, \qquad  p_x+ix~=~\sqrt{2H_x}e^{i\varphi_x}, \qquad  p_y+iy~=~\sqrt{2H_y}e^{i\varphi_y}. $$

References:

1. V.I. Arnold, *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics,* 1989; $\S$51 p. 291 Example 1.

Comment: I know that's unnecessary...but thank you!!